# reading app.config in Shared Add-In

Tags: c#, .net, excel, shared-libraries, app-config

I have created a shared Add-in for Excel and want to use App.config for some of the settings. I have read somewhere that i cant use app.config for shared Add in(dll). Please let me know is there any other way to read this config file

Comment: fyi normally if you want configuration for your dll you have <yourAssemblyName>.dll.config where your dll is <yourAssemblyName>.dll.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenExeConfiguration Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx) should help

Comment: by some ways not able to open ther url pls help me with the code